# Will Expo app exhibit this behaviour in production or is this limited to development?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, cross-platform

New to Expo and mobile app development as a whole. I made the following Navigation Bar, and I finally got it to look and behave exactly how I wanted. However, whenever I run my app on the Expo Go client on my Iphone 13 Pro Max (same issue when attempted to view on web), the center button on the Nav Bar just doesn't show up the first time the app loads up.

## NavItem.tsx

```
import { MaterialIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons"
import { Href, Link } from "expo-router"
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Pressable } from "react-native"

export default function NavItem({ id, title, iconName, active, url, passUp } : { id: number, title: string | undefined, iconName: keyof typeof MaterialIcons.glyphMap, active: boolean, url: Href<string>, passUp: (arg1: number) => void })
{
    return (
        <Pressable style={styles.NavItemWrapper}>
            <Link href={url} onPressOut={ () => { passUp(id) } } style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', zIndex: 2}} />
            <View style={styles.NavPress}>
                <MaterialIcons style={styles.NavIcon} name={iconName} color={(active ? global.baseGold100 : global.baseGrey100)} size={25} />
                <Text adjustsFontSizeToFit style={{fontSize: 10, color: (active ? global.baseGold100 : global.baseGrey100)}}>{title}</Text>
            </View>
        </Pressable>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    NavItemWrapper : {
        width: '15%',
        height: '100%',
    },

    NavPress : {
        position: 'absolute',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },

    NavIcon : {
        position: 'relative',
    },

    NavIconText : {
        fontSize: 10,
        position: 'relative',
    }
});
```

## NavBar.tsx

```
import { Link } from "expo-router";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import NavItem from "./NavItem";
import { MaterialIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { useState } from "react";


export default function NavBar(this: any)
{
    const itemIds = [0, 1, 2, 3];
    const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(0);

    function isActive( index : number ) : boolean {
        return activeTab === index
    }

    function swapTab(newTab : number) : void {
        setActiveTab(itemIds[newTab])
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.NavContainer}>
            <View style={styles.NavBox}>
                <NavItem id={0} active={ isActive(itemIds[0]) } passUp={swapTab} title='Home' iconName='home' url='/(tabs)/Home' />
                <NavItem id={1} active={ isActive(itemIds[1]) } passUp={swapTab} title='Explore' iconName='map' url='/(tabs)/Explore' />

                <View style={styles.NavCenterButton}>
                    <Link href='/(request)/Type' style={styles.NavCenterLink} />
                    <MaterialIcons color='#ffffff' name='add' size={35} />
                </View>

                <NavItem id={2} active={ isActive(itemIds[2]) } passUp={swapTab} title='Resources' iconName='bookmark' url='/(tabs)/Resources' />
                <NavItem id={3} active={ isActive(itemIds[3]) } passUp={swapTab} title='Profile' iconName='person' url='/(tabs)/Profile' />
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    NavContainer: {
        position: 'absolute',
        width: '100%',
        height: '7.5%',
        alignItems: 'center',
        bottom: 20
    },

    NavBox: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        height: '100%',
        width: '90%',
        justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderRadius: 25,
        shadowColor: "#000",
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: 5,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.33,
        shadowRadius: 6,
    },

    NavCenterButton: {
        width: '15%', 
        aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
        borderRadius: 28,
        backgroundColor: global.baseBlue100,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },

    NavCenterLink: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        position: 'absolute',
        zIndex: 2
    },
})
```

## Result

[image]

I try to reload over and over again like it tells me to but no change. But then, as soon as I go to make even one trivial change in these files (changing '#ffffff' to '#fff'), it pops back up immediately. At this point, even if I undo the change, the center button stays and behaves as it should. However, if I restart the client or restart the terminal on my machine, its back to square one.

## Proper Result (After Change)

[image]

My question is if this is just some weird, trivial behaviour on the development end and I can ignore it? My guess is this won't happen in production, am I correct? Is my code actually the problem? Like I said, new to React Native and Expo so not sure if I'm doing something terribly wrong.